# Python regex search until specific word and exclude everything behind it

Tags: python-3.x, regex, search

I have a script that always have the **"get the"** and the **"get"** in a string.
The **"ONE TWO THREE"** can vary, like it also can be **"THIRTEEN FORTY"** or **"SIX"**. After these variations there will always be a 2nd **"get"**.

I have the following code:

```
variable = 'get the ONE TWO THREE get FOUR FIVE'

myVariable = re.compile(r'(?<=get the) .*')
myVariableSearch = myVariable.search(variable)
mySearchGroup = myVariableSearch.group()
print(mySearchGroup) 

#prints ONE TWO THREE get FOUR FIVE
```

I want my script to exclude the 2nd **"get"** and everything behind it. My desired result is to be just the **"ONE TWO THREE"**.

How do I exclude this? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Use `r'(?<=\bget\sthe\s).*?(?=\s*\bget\b|\Z)'`

Comment: Thank you, just what I needed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
\bget\s+the\s+(.*?)(?=\s*\bget\b|$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/c1hbyr/1).

**Details**

- `\bget\s+the\s+`  - whole word `get`, 1+ whitespaces, `the`, 1+ whitespaces
- `(.*?)` - Group 1:
- `(?=\s*\bget\b|$)` - a positive lookahead that requires 0+ whitespaces and then a whole word `get`, or end of string immediately on the right of the current location.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/fP3fcL):

```
import re
variable = 'get the ONE TWO THREE get FOUR FIVE'
myVariableSearch = re.search(r'\bget\s+the\s+(.*?)(?=\s*\bget\b|$)', variable)
mySearchGroup = ''
if myVariableSearch:
    mySearchGroup = myVariableSearch.group(1)
print(mySearchGroup) 
# => ONE TWO THREE
```